# Jquery Input Mask Plugin with Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mvvm

I am trying to do the jquery input mask plugin with angular directive. when I try this one It's working but when I save it value is not coming. can any one please help me on this??.

My Script

```
 app.directive('maskrate', function ($http) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    $("#rateVal").mask("0.99");
                }
            }

        });
```

My Html

```
<input type="text" name="inputTaxRate" data-ng-model="taxRate.Rate" id="rateVal" class="form-control" maskrate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to update the `ng-model` value by your self, because the `mask input js` or the `maskrate` directive not going to change the `ng-model`value.

to do that your self, follow the below code.

```
app.directive('maskrate', function($http) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel', // requiring ng-model directive on the element
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        var jquery_element = $(element);
        jquery_element.mask("0.99");

        //listen for events on text element
        jquery_element.on('keyup paste focus blur', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();

            // update the ng-model value
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(val);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();

        })

      }
    }
});
```

`ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(val);` & `ngModelCtrl.$render();` responsible for the updating `ng-model` value.

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UpCGj6Fbde8oilXa9Ydl?p=preview)